# Expressions "Нет, я звонила!" and "Я так и знала!" in an answer

Tags: перевод

I need some confirmation that I understand correctly the  2 expressions mentioned in the title

To be clear, here is the whole dialog (taken from lesson 7 in the very helpful free learning website learnrussian.rt.com). There is translation of vocabulary but none for dialogs.

If you need to hear the intonation, you can listen to the dialog on the website itself (no registration needed if my memory's good).

3rd line & last line

> Жена: Где ты был?
>
> Муж: на работе ! Я был в офисе !
>
> Жена: **Нет, я звонила!** Где ты был?
>
> Муж: Я говорю, что я был на работе , в офисе .
>
> Жена: А потом?
>
> Муж: Потом я был в ресторане , на встрече .
>
> Жена: А потом?
>
> Муж: А потом я был в баре . Я и мой клиент…
>
> Жена: А потом?
>
> Муж: А потом… я был в клубе … на дискотеке …
>
> Жена: **Я так и знала!** Ты всегда отдыхаешь!

I would translate the beginning like this :

Wife: Where were you ?

Husband : At work ! I was at the office !

Wife : **No! I called you!**  *(i.e. you're lying, I tried to call you and you didn't answer)*

....
last :
Wife : **There, I knew it !** *(i.e. There you go, you're confessing,and I knew it in my mind!)*

I'm a bit confused on the use and meaning of "И"  in the latter. Is this just an usual way to talk ?

Comment: Confirmed! You are right in everything, including the guess about `и`.

Comment: Agree, all is correct. In sentences like "I did so" when it is said to agree or confirm the better/recommended option of behaviour, in Russian `и` used to make an enphasis: John: "You should ask him before." Mike: "I did it!" ( `я так и сделал` )

Comment: Perfect guesses. All correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You translated it absolutely correctly.

`Так и` has at least three meanings:

1. Как Х, так и Y - X as well as Y
2. (possible noun/pronoun) так и (verb), i. e. `я так и знала` - there, I knew it, `я так и сказал` - I told exactly this, `так и случилось` - that indeed happened.  That is your case.
3. `так и быть` - yandex dictionary translates it as a "all right, very well; so be it, right you are" but it means that you'll do what you asked to, but only as a favour.  So it should be translated as "as a favour" or "I'll do you a favour".

---

The word "и" has lots of meanings in Russians, some seemingly unrelated to "and".

Answer (score 3):

You were correct translating it.

“Нет, я звонила!” - "No, I called [to the office]";

“Я так и знала!” - "I knew it".

"И" in the last sentence must not be translated as "and" in that content.
Pronoun + "так и" + verb is a sentence structure which can confuse some.

"Я знала ..." - "I knew ..."

"Я так и знала!" - "I knew it!"

As you can see from the examples it finishes a particular thought without repetition and stressing it more.

Answer (score 2):

It would be very difficult to pronounce the phrase "я так и знала" without "и" - so this vowel exists here to make this phrase more smooth.